# Dell inspiron 13-7306 active pen configuration

Tags: bluetooth, dell, inspiron

I'm new to Linux, but took the brave decision to install Ubuntu on my newly ordered Dell inspiron 13-7306. So far most of the hardware seems to work, however the active pen that comes with it does not. I have been searching the internet for help but without success. I'm wondering if there are people with experience that can help me find the right driver and instructions on how to make this work. So far I only see that in the bluetooth settings there is connection established with what I assume to be the partnumber of the pen PN771M.
I'd appreciate your help.
Iwijn

Comment: Anything in the manual about how to pair it?

Comment: Since Dell says they support Ubuntu on their hardware I would be asking them.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I contacted Dell but without much luck. Probably I did not find the right contact that supports Ubuntu. They indicated that the driver is most probably part of the operating system. Couldn't find anything that would support my pen :(

Comment: @iwijn This pen is manufactured by Goodix/Shenzhen. There are a couple of drivers out there that support active pens, but none that currently support the `27c6:0111` Pen.  However, I'm actively trying to see if I might be able to add "third-party" support here: https://gitlab.com/AdyaAdya/goodix-touchscreen-linux-driver/-/issues/20

Comment: @Swivel ok, that is already a bit more info, thanks. Since I'm linux newby I'm not sure if I understand much of the various commands, but I'd be happy to experiment and learn and maybe get it working at some point.

Comment: @iwijn I totally understand. I was finally able to get things working after wrestling with things quite a bit. I found a solution that enables the pen but disables the touchscreen. And there are other solutions that preserve both, but they require recompiling drivers and things which can get messy. Check them out here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/486